# for loop and promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have three methods (each is a promise) that does SELECT from the database.

```
getDeliverDate()
           .then(calculateOrderList)
           .then(getOrderItemsForOrder)
```

For each deliverDate, I need to get the corresponding list of orders, and for each order I need to get the list of items. I will then build a JSONview to send to the client. To do that, I think I need to wrap the code above with a for loop, and presumably have a "global" object made of arrays etc.. and have to push to the object data from each method. I am not really sure if the approach will work. Can someone please tell me how to get it to work using the code above as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Push all the promises into an array then use Promise.all to wait for all promises to finish and return the result.  Something like

```
var promises = []

for (...) {
    promises.push(getDeliverDate()
           .then(calculateOrderList)
           .then(getOrderItemsForOrder));
}

return Promise.all(promises);
```

- Edit, `all` not `when` -- got my promise libraries confused

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do that is use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([getDeliverDate, calculateOrderList, getOrderItemsForOrder])
  .then(values => {
    console.log(values);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If what I understand is correct (as given in comments):

```
getDeliverDate()
    // get array of delivery dates
    .then((deliveryDates = []) => {
        // for each delivery date, I need to get corresponding list of orders
        const promises = deliveryDates.map(date => calculateOrderList(date));
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    // get order list as an array
    .then((orderList = []) => {
        // for each order I need to get list of items corresponding to that order
        const promises = orderList.map(order => getOrderItemsForOrder(order));
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    // get item list as an array
    .then((items) => console.log('got everything : ', items))
    .catch((error) => console.log('error : ', error))
```

Looks like you need a lot of API calls. Probably we should think about optimizing backend.

Comment: Thank you all, @free-soul, I am executing sql queries behind the three methods and returning a new Promise. like this getDeliverDates () return new Promise. In order to fit your code, I should remove the new Promise and use Promise.all code you provided. Is this correct?

Comment: No you don't need to touch any of your existing methods.